# Rendering chart to bitmap in memory from IRenderableSeriesViewModel

Tags: scichart

I have read up the guide on getting SciChart to render chart to memory on the support forums. However, the example there uses `FastLineRenderableSeries` whereas in my project, I am using `IRenderableSeriesViewModel` with series binding in XAML using `ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel>`.

When I try to follow the guide at [SciChart Knowledgebase](http://support.scichart.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/17213/34/rendering-chart-to-bitmap-in-memory), it uses `FastLineRenderableSeries` as `RenderableSeries`, and it doesn't work when I try to assign my pre-existing `ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel>` to `RenderableSeries` property under `SciChartSurface`.

I'd like to know if I could simply just use my existing `ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel>` when I am trying to export my existing plots to bitmap memory. I could just extract the `DataSeries` again from the `IRenderableSeriesViewModel` but if there is a faster way to do this, it would be great to know.

Thank you.

EDIT: I am trying to do the export this way, as seen in the Knowledgebase.

My ViewModel currently has this:

```
private ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel> seriesViewModels =
    new ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel>();

public ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel> SeriesViewModels
{
    get
    {
        return this.seriesViewModels;
    }
}
```

And as seen in the Knowledgebase,

```
var series = new FastLineRenderableSeries()
{
    SeriesColor = Colors.Red,
    DataSeries = GetDataSeries()
};

var surface = new SciChartSurface()
{
    ChartTitle = "Rendered In Memory",
    XAxes = xAxes,
    YAxes = yAxes,

    // Here, if I try to use "RenderableSeries = seriesViewModels" it doesn't work.
    RenderableSeries = new ObservableCollection() { series }
};

surface.Width = 1000;
surface.Height = 1000;

// Export to bitmap
var bitmapSource = surface.ExportToBitmapSource();
```

Visual studio will show this error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type Cannot implicitly convert type >
>   System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`<SciChart.Charting.Model.ChartSeries.IRenderableSeriesViewModel>` to System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`<SciChart.Charting.Visuals.RenderableSeries.IRenderableSeries>`

Would you have any suggestion regarding the relation between `IRenderableSeries` and `IRenderableSeriesViewModel`?

Comment: Hi Kurtis, are you using SciChartSurface.ExportToBitmapSource()? Does this work with the binding to ObservableCollection<IRednerableSeriesViewModel>? Care to share a code example? Please edit your question + comment here to notify me

Comment: Thank you Dr. ABT. I have updated my question with the code I'm trying to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation:

In order to map between `ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeriesViewModel>` and [SciChartSurface.RenderableSeries](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Visuals.SciChartSurface~RenderableSeries.html) which is of type `ObservableCollection<IRenderableSeries>` you need to use the [SeriesBinding](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/MVVM%20DataSeries%20RenderableSeries%20API.html) Markup Extension.

Typically, this is applied in XAML as follows:

```
<!-- Declare a SciChartSurface with SeriesBinding -->
<!-- Where xmlns:s="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart -->
    <s:SciChartSurface RenderableSeries="{s:SeriesBinding RenderableSeriesViewModels}">

    <!-- XAxis, YAxis omitted for brevity -->

</s:SciChartSurface>
```

So the problem becomes '[How to apply a MarkupExtension in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489789/set-custom-markupextension-from-code)', which is fairly difficult by the look of it.

You might be better off creating or styling the SciChartSurface in XAML and using [this.FindResource() to get your style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754644/303612) and apply it to the chart.

**EDIT: UPDATE**

Actually, I may have a solution for you. SciChart has the classes [RenderableSeriesConverter](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Common.Databinding.ToRenderableSeriesCollectionConverter.html) and [RenderableSeriesSourceCollection](http://www.scichart.com/documentation/v4.x/webframe.html#SciChart.Charting~SciChart.Charting.Model.ChartSeries.RenderableSeriesSourceCollection.html). Something like this might work:

```
var surface = new SciChartSurface()
{
    ChartTitle = "Rendered In Memory",
    XAxes = xAxes,
    YAxes = yAxes,

    RenderableSeries = new RenderableSeriesSourceCollection(seriesViewModels);
};
```

Magique!!

Comment: Got it. I think I'll go for the approach whereby I extract the DataSeries from my IRenderableSeriesViewModel and reconstruct the new IRenderableSeries.

Comment: Actually, I may have a solution for you. See my updated answer

Comment: Thank you. Your updated answer works perfectly with my existing collection.