# Is there a way to assign a dynamic resource to a dependency property in code

Tags: c#, xaml, dependency-properties, code-behind, resourcedictionary

I have a SolidColorBrush defined in a Resource Dictionary as follows:

```
 <Color x:Key="ColorGray100">#F5F6F7</Color>

 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BrushGray100" Color="{DynamicResource ColorGray100}" />
```

I have a Dependency Property defined in the code behind for a user control as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// get/set the brush for the pattern ring.
    /// The pattern ring is a full circle which the progress ring is drawn over.
    /// This Brush value is defaulted to Brushes.LightGray
    /// </summary>
    public Brush PatternRingBrush
    {
        get => (Brush)GetValue(PatternRingBrushProperty);
        set => SetValue(PatternRingBrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PatternRingBrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PatternRingBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(UXProgressRing),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.LightGray));
```

How can I assign the "BrushGray100" SolidColorBrush as the default UIPropertyMetadata value instead of Brushes.LightGray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to assign a dynamic resource to dependency property's default value. (Nor would it make sense because the default value is evaluated once, whereas a dynamic resource can by definition change)

However, if your goal is to assign the actual dependency property value to a dynamic resource, effectively binding the property to the dynamic resource, there already exist answers on this site that describe how to do that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754658/9884514) appears to be the best existing solution.

I'm posting this as an answer instead of marking as duplicate because your question specifically asks about setting the *default* value.